# Dynamics CRM Fetch DynamicEntities Including Properties with null Values

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm fetching a bunch of DynamicEntities using RetrieveMultipleRequest/Response with a simple query expression. The resulting entities don't seem to include Properties when the value is null in the response.

Is it possible to make Dynamics to return Property instances where the value is null?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the reason for returning NULL-values?

Comment: I want to loop over all the properties on the entity and change the values of some of them based on an external data source (synchronization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is by design and cannot be changed. You will also see the same behavior when requesting data with FetchXML.

I had a conversation with a developer of the CRM team which described this decision with performance benefits.

To get information about the metadata of entities, there exists another web service. The [metadata service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151047.aspx). To get the metadata for a specific entity you have to send a [RetrieveEntityRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc156229.aspx). It will return an instance of [EntityMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb890357.aspx) which contains all meta information about the entity

Comment: How can I find out what types of properties are available on an entity?